# syntax error ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails from pragmatic programmers 'Agile Web Development with Rails'.

I have wrote a small application and when it runs I receive the following syntax error when I run it:

```
/Users/colinlabri/Desktop/depot/app/models/product.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':',   expecting keyword_end
  attr_accessible : title, :description, :image_url, :price
                   ^
/Users/colinlabri/Desktop/depot/app/models/product.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
  attr_accessible : title, :description, :image_url, :price
                                        ^
 Rails.root: /Users/colinlabri/Desktop/depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The code for the DB is as follows:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string : title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Versions are as follow:
ruby 1.9.3p362
Rails 3.2.11

Should I be checking my sqlite installation and how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix this line:

```
t.string : title
```

to:

```
t.string :title
```

Your model also has the same problem in the `attr_accessible` call.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I should have known that! I have changed the above and saved the file now I get,Could not find table 'products'

Comment: Most likely your migration failed to run, or you haven't run it before. Try `rake db:migrate` from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`:something` are actually symbols in Ruby. You cannot leave any space between `:` and the symbol name.

Change `t.string : title` to `t.string :title` in the migration file.

And in your product model,

Change `attr_accessible : title` to `attr_accessible :title`

Comment: Thank you, I now get Could not find table 'products'?